# is there any way to make some part of vue as a moudle

Tags: vue.js

for example :
I have a vue project contains "userCenter" and now I need a new branch of this project . In the new project , the some part of "userCenter.vue" is diffrent while the others are same .

Actually I need to deal with a lots of this issu and I thought two solutions:

1. create branch
2. change the "***.vue"

questions comes:

when I make branches , I need to deal every branch to fix-up changes might appear latter,
when I make changes in "***.vue" , with all the changes my project will contains many useless code .

so I want's to know could I make the common part as module like developing android?

by my poor english , I'm a chinese . If you too ,communicate with chinese will help a lot ！

Thanks

Comment: The question isn't specific enough. Can you explain what kind of differences there are? What are the purposes of these branches? "all the changes my project will contains many useless code", like developing android" - what is this about?

Comment: the diffrences may be : visible or invisible for dom , diffrence implemenatinon for one click funtion , or diffrent part view .

Comment: These could be modules (libs) indeed that are conditionally imported. And/or some components could be injected per app, e.g. in Vue.component(...), so different comps would have the same comp names